# Google App Engine Datastore Concurrent Modification Exception

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

```
java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
java.util.HashMap$HashIterator.nextEntry(HashMap.java:806)
java.util.HashMap$KeyIterator.next(HashMap.java:841)
java.util.AbstractCollection.addAll(AbstractCollection.java:333)
java.util.HashSet.(HashSet.java:117)
org.datanucleus.ObjectManagerImpl.persistObject(ObjectManagerImpl.java:1599)
org.datanucleus.api.jdo.JDOPersistenceManager.jdoMakePersistent(JDOPersistenceManager.java:731)
org.datanucleus.api.jdo.JDOPersistenceManager.makePersistent(JDOPersistenceManager.java:756)
```

The above exception is throwing when trying to persist object. Iterating array using for each and persisting object one by one from the array using makePersistent method.

Comment: You may want to try object mapping frameworks like Twist: http://git.io/OGKDBQ instead

Answer (score 0):

This can happen if the same entity is being updated by multiple threads. [See this link](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/transactions#Java_Uses_for_transactions) for some documentation providing insight into why this might occur.

Also remember that makePersistent() behind the scenes is doing a put() in the low-level API, but not necessarily at the moment you call makePersistent().

I hope this helps you track down what's happening for your app.